# Using user input from arcGis to chose certain csv column

Tags: python, csv, arcgis

I'm currently a beginner in coding and very new in python coding.

I actually wanted to rewrite csv file (*read csv and save it to another csv*)

What I'm gonna ask you is how to read a certain csv column from arcGis User input.

I use "field" datatypes and "multivalues" for input so i can choose which column i want to display.

For example, i have this csv:

```
    key, province, population, area
    A1, provA, 100, 20
    B1, provB, 200, 10
    C1, provC, 50, 30
```

Now from input i choose only key and area for column, i use:

```
    GetParameterAsText(0)
```

then i use this code:

```
    headers = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    newhead = headers.replace("'", "")
    headersList = newhead.split(";")
    arcpy.AddMessage(headersList)
```

i got this result (*headersList*):

```
    [u'key', u'area']
```

The **Problem** starts when i want to read that certain column from the above result:

```
    data = []
    with csvdata as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        for row in reader:
            try:
                new_row = [headersList] <--------------- This One
                data.append(new_row)
            except IndexError as e:
                print e
                pass

        with open(csvout, "w+") as to_file:
            writer = csv.writer(to_file, delimiter=",")
            for new_row in data:
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

I want to make new_row to like this (get it from *headersList*):

```
    new_row = [row['key'], row['area']]
```

But i just don't know how, can anyone help?

Comment: Assuming `headersList` is `[u'key', u'area']`, what about `new_row = [row[k] for k in headersList]`  (This is called a list comprehension)

Comment: wow, I can do that? let me try it

Comment: That works great!, I've changed a few codes to get my result, thanks sir...

Now i know there is something called list comprehension

Comment: No problem, comprehensions are an extremely powerful tool to have in your toolbox!  And make sure to accept your own answer too :)

Comment: Yeah, i'm not allowed to accept it in 2 days, haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @jedwards comment, the answer is like this:

```
data = []
with csvdata as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        try:
            new_row = [row[k] for k in headersList]
            data.append(new_row)
        except IndexError as e:
            print e
            pass

    with open(csvout, "wb") as to_file:
        writer = csv.writer(to_file, delimiter=",")
        writer.writerow(headersList)
        for new_row in data:
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Thanks Again!